# How to display a (two dimensional) string array in react-native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I'm trying to display a 2 dimensional string array in my react-native code, that is passed on from the native code. Passing the code is not a problem, however I don't really get how to properly display this array. For testing purposes, I made the message array a constant in the js code.

Here is my array:

```
const messageArray = [
  ["msg1", "date1"],
  ["msg2", "date2"],
  ["msg3", "date3"],
  ["msg4", "date4"],
  ["msg5", "date5"]
];
```

How do I render this into a view?

Comment: Render is as what? A table?

Comment: I think your post needs some more info. Where is the code? What did you try? Did you have any errors? etc.

Comment: All my attempts were complete failures, so it wouldt make any sense to post them. I basically just needed to render it as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can do it. You can use **destructuring**.

```js
const messageArray = [
  ["msg1", "date1"],
  ["msg2", "date2"],
  ["msg3", "date3"],
  ["msg4", "date4"],
  ["msg5", "date5"]
];

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {messageArray && messageArray.map(([message, date]) =>
          <div className='msg-item'>
            message: {message || ''}
            <br />
            date: {date || ''}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.msg-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.msg-item + .msg-item {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! this is however "normal" react code in comparison to react-native code, but after conversion it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using the answer of jank, for anyone with the same issue:

```
const messageArray = [
  ["msg1", "date1"],
  ["msg2", "date2"],
  ["msg3", "date3"],
  ["msg4", "date4"],
  ["msg5", "date5"]
];

export default class App extends Component {

    Render(){
        <View>
            {messageArray && messageArray.map(([message, date]) => <View>
            <Text>message: {message || ''}</Text>
            <Text>date: {date || ''}</Text>
            </View>)}
       </View>

}
```